# How to print all females in prolog if my facts only contains male property

Tags: prolog

Lets suppose my db.pl file consists of only

```
male(Oliver)
male(james) 
male(sam) 

female(X) :- \+ male(X)
```

Now if I query,

> ?- male(X).

Then this will successfully return all the males.
But if I query,

> ?- female(X)

Then this will not. However, if I put a name in the female predicate, it correctly gives the output as yes/no.
What am I missing here? How do I get the list of all females? Or basically list of "not male".

Comment: This is the main issue with negation as failure (compared to negation in classical logic). Where should the list of all females come from? One possibility would be to introduce a `person/1` predicate and then define `female(X) :- person(X), \+ male(X).` but at as soon as `X` can contain variables you get this effect.

Comment: Btw. you probably want to define `male(oliver)`, otherwise everyone is male (`Oliver` is a variable).

Comment: thanks @lambda.xy.x , it was a typing error.

Comment: If your db.pl file consists of only those lines, what female names are you expecting to get?? all possible combinations of letters except those defined as male? `a, aa, ab, ac, ad ..., sak, sal, san, sao...`  but not sam?

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd give a proper answer as well. As mentioned in the comments, the fact `male(Oliver).` contains the variable `Oliver` such that e.g. also `male(catherine_the_great)` succeeds. But fixing this mistake will not solve the problem. Suppose we fix the facts for male and define female as above:

```
male(oliver)
male(james) 
male(sam) 

female(X) :-
  \+ male(X).
```

Then we can not derive `male(catherine_the_great)` anymore but `female(catherine_the_great)` succeeds:

```
?- male(catherine_the_great).
false.

?- female(catherine_the_great).
true.
```

Unfortunately, by this definition, a hamburger is also female:

```
?- female(hamburger).
true.
```

What's even worse is, when we ask if there exists someone female (at all!), we get no as an answer:

```
?- female(X).
false.
```

The reason for this is that `\+` is not classical negation(*) but what is called [weak negation / negation as failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure). `\+ male(X)` is true if there is no `X` such that `male(X)` is derivable. But as soon as `male/1` succeeds with any solution (e.g. `male(oliver)`), the negation fails. In such cases the substitution `male(X)` is not proper substiution for `female(X)` but how are we supposed to get a list of all women? A possible solution is a list of persons of which we define `male`/`female` as subsets:

```
person(oliver).
person(james). 
person(sam). 
person(jackie).
person(selma).

male(oliver).
male(james). 
male(sam). 

female(X) :-
  person(X),
  \+ male(X).
```

When we query a list of all women, we now get:

```
?- female(X).
X = jackie ;
X = selma.
```

I'd rather use a separate predicate listing women though because it is less error prone when adding new persons.

In general, negation as failure is rarely safe. Two rules of thumb i have for myself:

- whenever `\+ p(X)` appears as a goal, it is fully instantiated (a ground term). In our case, this is what `person` assures.
- `p(X)` terminates for every ground term `X`. This assures termination of the negation as well.

(*) in classical logic, the rule of generalization female(jackie) → ∃X female(X) holds but here we can not derive ∃X female(X) despite being able to derive female(jackie).